# Export array ReactJS - error: array is read-only

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, export

I'm trying to export a variable with React to another file.

I have an array, which I want to use in multiple files. In one file it should be emptied when a button has been pressed.

**myArray.js**

```
export var myArray = [];
```

**app.js**

```
import {myArray} from './myArray.js';
function resetArray(){
  myArray = [];
}
```

Webpack gives the following error:

> ERROR in ./app.js Module build failed: SyntaxError:
>   "myArray" is read-only

How can I make it not read only but adjustable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider a different approach here. Essentially you're working against the principle of uni-directional data flow that makes React work.

You should redesign this so that in your main React component, you set this array as state. Then pass that array down as props to the child components that need access to the array.

Then if you want a child component to change the array, you need to pass a function down called something like `updateMyArray`, which that component then calls on the top component.

Something like this:

```
class MainComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    myArray: ['a','b','c']
  }

  updateMyArray(newArray) {
    this.setState({myArray: newArray})
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
        <ChildComponent updateArray={this.updateMyArray} myArray={this.state.myArray} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Then in the child component you can call `this.props.updateMyArray(someNewArray)` whenever is appropriate and it will re-render from the top with the new array passed down to the child in props.

Comment: Thank you. I also thought I was going wrong way. Thanks for the explaination, it works now.